# display array elements in order based on condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array namely $checked_posts which looks like -

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 15
)
```

This array contains the id's of the posts which are selected.
I fetch data from database like -

```
$q=mysql_query("select ID,post_title from sa_posts
                where post_author='".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."'
                and post_type='post'
                and post_status='publish'
                order by ID desc
              ");
```

This query fetch id and post_title
I want to compare array $checked_posts value(id) with select queries fetch id
If both match then I want to show that record early, if not then such records should be display after all selected records.
Suppose my $checked_post array contains -

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 15
)
```

and my select query fetch records(id's) like 15,13,20,25,32 in such conditions I have to display the records firstly where the id matches and later I want to display all unmatched elements.
I have tried so far -

```
$q=mysql_query("select ID,post_title from sa_posts
                where   post_author='".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."'
                and post_type='post'
                and post_status='publish'
                order by ID desc
               ");                           
                while($p=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                {
                    if(in_array($p['ID'],$checked_posts))
                    {
                           $check_post='checked'; // I want to display all these elements firstly and later all unmatched elements.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           $check_post='';
                        }
echo "<li class='menu_post_list' id='".$m_n."' style='list-style:none;display:".$disp_post."'>
<input type='checkbox' value='".$p['ID']."' class='menu_list_post' $check_post> ".$p['post_title']."</li>";  
                 }
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: From where do you get the checked_posts array?Do you have in db a column with checked?

Comment: @Mihai From the name, my guess is it comes from checkboxes on a form.

Comment: @Mihai I get $checked_post array from another select query.

Comment: Then I suppose you only need a JOIN with the other field where you get the checked values,no need for php array manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can JOIN the checked IDs since they come from the db,no need for php operations

```
select ID,post_title from sa_posts 
        JOIN someOtherTable ON sa_posts.ID=someoOtherTable.checkedIds
                where   post_author='".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."'
                and post_type='post'
                and post_status='publish'
                order by ID desc
```

Comment: @ Mihai In one db table i have stored ids like 1,5,7,15(comma separated) so how would I use join query?

Comment: @Deepak `..JOIN... ON FIND_IN_SET(sa_posts.ID,someoOtherTable.checkedIds)`

Comment: @ Mihai It is working but showing only matched records.

Comment: @Deepak Use left JOIN and also add the FIND_IN_SET in the ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting the check into the `ORDER BY` clause of the query.

```
$checked_str = implode(',', $checked_posts);

$q=mysql_query("select ID,post_title from sa_posts
            where   post_author='".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."'
            and post_type='post'
            and post_status='publish'
            order by ID IN ($checked_posts) DESC, ID desc
           ");
```

You can also avoid doing the `in_array()` test in the PHP code by adding this to the query results:

```
$q=mysql_query("select ID,post_title, ID IN ($checked_posts) as checked
            from sa_posts
            where   post_author='".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."'
            and post_type='post'
            and post_status='publish'
            order by checked DESC, ID desc
           ");
```

Then the PHP code can just use

```
$check_post = $p['checked'] ? 'checked' : '';
```